# Specifying bearings doesn't provide the routes in the same direction

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

`/route/v1/driving/-78.10131888342865,41.56893770131277%3B-78.511866,41.648554?alternatives=true&steps=true&overview=full&bearings=315,24;0,359`

Above is the API call to OSRM with a specific attention to the bearings. The intention is to specify the current direction that the user is heading towards relative to the true North and provide a tolerance level so that the route provided by OSRM would be in the same direction as the current direction of the user.  315 is the direction that the user is heading which is roughly North West and 24 is the allowable variance in bearing. For destination, the direction can be from anywhere.

However, the provided response from OSRM is constantly in the opposite direction of the current heading of the user. I've tried the tolerance level to be anywhere between 90 all the way down to 0, but still only getting the directions in the opposite direction.

To eliminate the possibility that it could be due to the restrictions on the roads nearby, I've tried on multiple different roads as well as different destinations.

How to fix this?